# Evaluating the Triple Integrals Upper and Lower Bounds?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$\iiint_T$ $xy\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where $T$ is the first-octant solid bounded by the coordinates planes and the upper half of there sphere $ x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4$.

Since this is a circle the radius is 2.

$x^2= -y^2-z^2+4$

$ y^2 = -x^2-z^2+4$

---

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{-y-z+2}\int_{0}^{-x-z+2}xy\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

I think I am on the right track but I feel that there is a piece missing in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic ideas are correct, but you have to be careful with the order of the integration(do not forget the roots and squares)

First of all I think you meant this:

$\int_{0}^{2}$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{-y^2-z^2+4}}$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{-x^2-z^2+4}}$ $xy, dxdydz$

But there is still the problem that you first integrate with respect to $x$ but at the same time you have $x$ in the limits, this does not make sence. So first we know integrate $x$ and the limits should only depend on $y$ and $z$, so we can take the upper bound $\sqrt{4-y^2-z^2}$. Then we integrate w.r.t to $y$, so the upper bound must be $\sqrt{4-z^2}$ and at last for $z$ the limits $0$ and $2$, then we get:

$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^2-z^2}}xy dxdydz$

EDIT: You can imagine it as integrating first over the $x$-values to get the integral over 'line'. Then we integrate over lines and get the integral of over the 'area'(slice) then we integrate over all those slices to get the integral over the whole voluem. (This is basically the idea of fubinis theorem. Perhaps you can make a sketch in order to visualize it.)

$\int_{0}^{2}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^2-z^2}}xy dx}_{\text{Int. over x-values at $(y,z)$}}dy}_{\text{Int. over Area of slice at $z$}}dz$

But I recommend using spherical coordinates, which makes integrating much easier.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on how you got $\sqrt{4-z^2}$ ?

Comment: I just updated my answer, I hope that helps! $\sqrt{4-z^2}$ is basically the upper limit of the $y$ values at the given $z$ position.

Comment: How would this look sketched figuratively speaking?

Comment: Well the Riemann integral is constructed via a limit process where you sum up discrete values and consider what happens if you make those slices smaller and smaller. Here you just basically have a volume, that get sliced in one direction $dz$ and each of those 2d slices gets sliced in another direction $dy$ which again get sliced in the third direction $dc$.

Answer (score 0):

First, $x^2=-y^2-z^2+4$ does not imply $x=-y-z+2$. The best we can do here is $x=\sqrt{-y^2-z^2+4}$, the positive square root because the region is in the first octant. If your innermost integral is with respect to $x$ then this is the suitable upper bound. Similarly, $y^2=-x^2-z^2+4$ and so $y=\sqrt{-x^2-z^2+4}$, but this cannot be the upper bound for the $y$ integral as we should have already integrated $x$. To find the upper bound, think about the region in the $yz$-plane that this solid would be projected down onto. This is precisely the condition that $x=0$, and so the correct upper bound for this integral can be obtained by substituting $x=0$ into $y=\sqrt{-x^2-z^2+4}$. The $z$ bound can be found in a similar manner, projecting onto the $z$ axis, i.e. setting $x=y=0$ and as you determined, the upper bound is $2$. Therefore the correct integral settup is$$\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{-z^2+4}}\int_0^{\sqrt{-y^2-z^2+4}}xy\hspace{1ex}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z.$$